# Is this loop invariant and its informal proof correct? (CLRS 3rd ed. exercise 2-1-3)

Tags: algorithm, search, clrs, loop-invariant

Given the following algorithm for linear-search (referring to index 1 as the index of the first element in an array of elements):

```
found_idx = nil
for i = 1 to A.length
  if A[i] == value
    found_idx = i
    return found_idx
  end-if
end-for
found_idx
```

I was wondering if this loop-invariant is correct:
" At the start of each iteration of the for-loop, found_idx is the index in the array ending at i-1 at which value exists if that value exists"

Here is my proposed informal explanation of this loop-invariant according to the format in CLRS:

1. *Initialization*: This is true before the first iteration because i = 1 and the array ending at i-1 is empty, and found_idx is therefore nil.
2. *Maintenance*: This is true after each iteration because at each value of `i`, `A[i]` is checked and **then** `i` is incremented, meaning that all elements up to `i-1` have been checked prior to each new iteration.
3. *Termination*: This terminates when `i > A.length`, meaning that all elements up to and including `A.length` have been checked.

My main point of concern is that it feels incorrect to refer to the index ending at `i-1` because the loop starts with `i` at 1, which is the first element of the array. In other words, it feels fallacious to refer to a subarray of an array, wherein the subarray ends at an index less than the starting index of the array for which the subarray is supposed to be a subarray in the first place. This seems to imply that the loop invariant given above is actually false before the *very first* iteration of the loop.

Thoughts?

Comment: Now `found_idx` is useless: you could `return i` in the middle, and drop `found_idx` altogether, because the loop never reaches the end with `found_idx` assigned.

Comment: Well the loop will reach the end if value is not found in the array, won't it?

Comment: Right, in which case `found_idx` would remain `nil`.

Comment: Yes that's the intention. So, perhaps there are a couple problems with the loop invariant I proposed? I'm more concerned with how to approach constructing the appropriate loop invariance and subsequently using it properly than I am with the elegance or terseness of the pseudocode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the loop terminates early, its invariant is as follows:

```
found_idx = nil && ∀k<i : A[k] ≠ value
```

The part after `&&` means "All of `A`'s elements at indexes below `i` are not equal to `value`".

- This is trivially true before entering the loop
- Conditional either keeps `found_idx` at `nil`, or terminates the loop early
- Loop terminates when `i` reaches `A.length`

Loop's post-condition is `found_idx = nil && ∀k<A.length : A[k] ≠ value`, which simply means that `value` is not among `A`'s elements. It also means that you can eliminate `found_idx` by rewriting your loop as follows:

```
for i = 1 to A.length
    if A[i] == value
        return i
    end-if
end-for
return nil
```